# How to center two markers with react native map view

Tags: reactjs, react-native-maps

I got two markers at two different coordinates.

How do people normally center two markers so that you can see two marker at the same time on map, regardless how far away they are.

```
<MapView 
ref={ (map)=> this.map = map}
initialRegion={this.state.init} 
style={css.map}>    
    { this.state.marker1 !==0 && <MapView.Marker 
        coordinate={{
            'latitude':this.state.marker1.lat,
            'longitude':this.state.marker1.lng}}
        />}
    { this.state.marker2 !==0 && <MapView.Marker 
        coordinate={{
            'latitude':this.state.marker2.lat,
            'longitude':this.state.marker2.lng}}
        />}
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fitToSuppliedMarkers` or `fitToCoordinates` method of the `MapView`.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

Comment: fitToSuppliedMarkers only takes one markerId, and fitToCoordinates only takes only lat and one lng. Both of them dont center multiple markers

Comment: hmm? I believe `fitToSuppliedMarkers` takes an array `markerIDs: String[]`

Comment: how you gonna format that array? like this ? [lat1,lat2,lng1,lng2]

Comment: Assuming your markers are already on screen, every marker can have an `identifier` property. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md
This is the ID that you would pass into `markerIDs: String[]`.

Comment: Otherwise, to use `fitToCoordinates`, you could map the coordinates of all your `Marker` into an array of coordinates with `{ latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number }`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone like me who comes across this, what you need is `fitToSuppliedMarkers` from MapView and `identifiers` from Marker. Here is an example:  https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/FitToSuppliedMarkers.tsx

Answer (score -1):

You need to use fitToSuppliedMarkers or fitToCoordinates method of the MapView in ComponentDidMount or useEffect and make sure you put it in a setTimeout or it will cause performance problems.

```js
useEffect(() => {
if (!destination) return;

setTimeout(() => {
  mapRef?.current?.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["destination", "origin"], {
    edgePadding: { top: 70, right: 70, bottom: 70, left: 70 },
  });
}, 500);

// console.log("2", destination);
  }, [origin, destination]);
```

Note edgePadding is Google Maps only
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33442670)